# Mobile view and desktop view showing different messages when chat banned

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, chat-ban

When viewing any room now on MSE chat on mobile device (or desktop with mobile theme), I see the following message:

> [image: read only message]

Or in text:

> This room is read-only

While this is technically true (it is read only for me since I'm chat banned), this implies the room is in gallery mode, so nobody (other than RO and approved users) can talk there.

The full site theme already has a friendly and useful message instead:

> [image: friendly ban message]

Can this message be applied in mobile theme as well?

Comment: @Sonic I wouldn't call it "wrong", as I mentioned in the question, this is *technically* true.

Comment: The *room* is not read-only; otherwise other users wouldn't be able to post either.

Comment: @Sonic please, **stop** editing. Thanks. (I also tagged this as bug, so if you're correct and it's a bug, it's covered. By wording it this way I make it clear it might not be a bug.)

Comment: There is **no** question that it's a bug. The assertion that the room is "read-only" makes no sense because other users can post as well. Sure, it may be read-only for *you*, but it's not *overall* read-only. If the message were saying "this room is read-only for you", it would be correct, but it says "this message is read-only", which implies that it's overall read-only to everyone. It's definitely the wrong message.

Comment: @Sonic it is read only for the logged in user. I guess that used to be the message on the full site theme too in the beginning, but when changing that to a friendly message they forgot to apply in mobile theme.

Comment: @Sonic also, making this a wording bug would be technically correct, but not my point, and with lower chances of being done,

Comment: As I said, saying "this room is read-only" is wrong if it's only for the logged-in user; it should say "this room is read-only for you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed since September 28.

When I implemented the fix to [1 rep user requesting access to a gallery chatroom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358097/1-rep-user-requesting-access-to-a-gallery-chatroom/374690#374690), I made the mobile messages and logic match the desktop, including when banned.  If you get banned from chat again, you'll see the right message.

**Please don't try getting yourself banned from chat to verify that this is fixed.**

Comment: Well I can get my sock to be banned... ;-)